# Does anybody know how hazelcast distributed service works?

Tags: java, hazelcast

Am new to hazelcast and we are trying to utilize hazelcasts distributed executor service for task execution on remote machines? But I am curious to know how does a code which resides in your client application and compiled in client Jar gets executed on remote machine? How the remote machine knows about the code/instructions. For ex below code

```
HazelcastInstance newHazelcastClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        IExecutorService executorService = newHazelcastClient.getExecutorService("xyz");
        executorService.submit(new Callable<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Am being executed on server");
                return null;
            }
        });
```

This code is compiled and resides in client jar then how does server knows about it

Comment: You need to deploy those classes on the server, otherwise he won't know them.

Comment: Here I am trying to connect to a remote hazelcast server from a hazelcastClient and then execute this code.

Comment: Here what I mean am running a server and client in different JVM

Comment: Yeah you need to have the classes on both ends, client and server.

Comment: A new feature called user-code deployment is being added at 3.9 release, which will let you deploy client code at the server and not require the additional jar deployments at the server side.